# OIDC and service worker

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, service-worker, browser-based

Recently I was reading OIDC documentation for browser based aplications and I found that one of the recomendation is to use service worker (you can see it [here](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-10.html#name-tokens-securely-handled-by-)). I'm quite fresh to service workers but I know that it is possible to intercept fetch, so it is possible to add access token to each external api request. The problem is how should I safely store token? Can I just cache it caling `const cache = await caches.open("my-cahce");` and then just add token to the cache?

Comment: The very document you link tells you how to store the tokens: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps#name-token-storage-in-the-browse

Comment: @user229044 indeed there is a section about how to store tokens but it is not clear form me how to handle in service worker. Recomendation: "the Service Worker MUST NOT store tokens in any persistent storage API that is shared with the main window" still don't says how to store token. Do I understand correctly that using service worker is not a good idea for now because there isn't storage that is private in service worker context?

Comment: see this video about why you should not store tokens in the browser https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw

Comment: @Mateusz You're meant to let the service worker do the authorization flow, so the token never touches your non-sevice worker code.  Unless you need to access the token from JavaScript, use an HTTPOnly Secure cookie and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

The service worker is isolated from the page and you can store a token inside it in a variable or in a closure - this is safe.